# Spyder with Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 - how to change from one to the other?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using an iMac running high sierra. I'm using Spyder to teach myself python. I'm using the Anaconda distribution of both python 2.7 and 3.6. I have used conda to create two virtual environments. When I activate one of these environments Spyder uses the version of python defined for that environment. My question: is it possible to change which version of python you use without quitting Spyder and activating the other environment?

Comment: I really don't think that's possible!

Comment: Preferences --> Python interpreter? Although the default is described as "i.e. the same as Spyder's" which is confusing because I would have assumed that was the Python interpreter I was setting...

Comment: I looked into that but got a warning that doing so could cause many problems so I didn't try it.  I was hoping there was a "legal" way.